# How to turn this .dlu file type into a complete readable text, identification of the file etc

Tags: format

I´ve got this file type with this .dlu ending
In this case it is the file dspmf_a3.dlu
The internet is telling me that this file type is used for/in some very expensive 3D program (3ds Max Utility Plug-in) which isn´t very plausible

```
S01A003400004D616B654453503A206473706D665F61332E646C7572
S32500340000001FC3EF00000000000235280034012841532D31313031000000000044535000AE
S32500340020000000000000000000000000446AF1C4000000046473706D665F61332E646C759F
S32500340040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000066
S3250034006000000000435353204453502050524F4752414D20415245410000000000000000E5
S32500340080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000026
S325003400A0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
S325003400C00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000E6
S325003400E00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000C6
S325003401000000000000000000444355000000000000000000000000000000000000000000C9
```

These are the first 10 lines of code, opened with the standard-editor the program is displayed as hex-code?

The complete file has 4524 lines of this.

I tried to convert these lines with a standard hex to text converter, it gives me more gibberish than clear words but it translates some of the code but with a lot of little shields with 4 Zeros between the words.

https://www.online-toolz.com/tool/hex-to-text-converter

```
MakeDSP: dspmf_a3.dlur
```

The internet suggests some programs to open this file type, but these sites seems to auto-fill? their content on the topic of .dlu files.

They suggest programs like the "Dragon UnPACKer" which my Trend Micro antivirus program doesn´t like. Here again this unpacker is described as something to extract stuff from PAK-files of games.

The hexedit program HxD didn´t work either for me.

It would be a great help if someone knew how to simply open this file-type with correct syntax.

I am a complete beginner in this field? and will try to give more information if asked.